How is ComfyUI wasting so much RAM?
I'm doing image generation in ComfyUI with CPU. I noticed the high RAM usage, often leading to an out-of-memory kill at the end of generation (usually during VAE decoding), and so I looked for options to reduce RAM usage. The only good thing I found is "--force-fp16". Using SaveLatent and LoadLatent nodes to do the VAE decoding separately also seemed to help at first, but now I'm not so sure any more. I even wrote my own custom node to save and load conditionings (i.e. the output of the CLIP encoder) in the hope of reducing RAM usage further by separating the CLIP encoding from the main loop, but when actually measuring the peak RAM usage, my custom nodes made no appreciable difference, indicating that ComfyUI might indeed be unloading the CLIP model after use instead of keeping it in RAM. That makes it even stranger that peak RAM usage is over 3 times the size of the entire model on disk. Given that the file seems to be FP16 and contains the diffusion model, the CLIP model and the VAE, this RAM usage seems excessive. I could understand an overhead of maybe 20% over the size of the diffusion model, but actual peak RAM usage is almost 4 times the size of the diffusion model.
So my question is: What the hell is going on? pytorch can't be that inefficient and I see no further comfyui-options to guarantee lower RAM usage.
I measured this with a 2.5GB Stable Diffusion 2.1 model, RAM usage peaked at 7.5GB. But other models also had large overhead.
PS: Related to this question might be that using even just 1 Lora seemed to double the RAM usage relative to just the base model, even though the Lora file was tiny compared to the base model. I would have expected ComfyUI to directly patch the base model and then throw away the Lora, but doubling the RAM usage instead hints at ComfyUI keeping a second full copy of the base model in RAM, for no apparent reason.
